# How can I add n times a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

The example is below. I want to add n player numbers and replace the player1 for player# where # is a variable counter using something like addend on a list.

this is the code

```
from random import randint
game={'player1':randint(1,6),
      'player2':randint(1,6),
      'player3':randint(1,6)}
```

The print is: {'player1': 2, 'player2': 2, 'player3': 5}

I want something like:

```
from random import randint
for c in range(1,8)
game={f'player{c}':randint(1,6)}
```

The print is: {'player3': 5}

Comment: The first code block does not result in the print you're claiminig, and I strongly doubt that second codeblock prints anything other than `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, so please [post your real code](/help/how-to-ask), never just write code in your post without actually verifying that what you wrote does what you claim it does.

Comment: use dictionary comprehension: `game = {f'player{c}': randint(1,6) for c in range(1,8)}`